Mary UI Choices Component Not Working Correctly After Installation
I have a little question why my mary ui does not work correct. I installed it like the installation guy and most of the ui kit is working. But the choices does not work correct.
I implement it as this:
<x-mary-choices label="Employee" wire:model="user_id" :options="$employees" single searchable /> 
and in frontend it looks like this:
enter image description here
enter image description here
like the mary ui guide but it didnt worked

The reason you get this behavior is most likely because you used Laravel Breeze to create your project and that comes with tailwindcss-forms. If you take a look at your tailwind.config.js file you can remove forms from the plugins and it should look like it's supposed to.
